# Build Action is not support in this configuration in Netbeans 8.0

Tags: html, netbeans, configuration, build, action

When I try to build my HTML5 project i get the error message saying "Build Action is not support in this configuration.".  I am trying to get a .war file of my project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either Java Web or JavaEE project type to get war file, not HTML5